# FlatFileItemWriter to append when writing

Tags: spring-batch

how could I make an itemWriter to instead of empting the file then write in it, to simply append what the write has to write.

I'm using a FlatFileItemWriter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fileItemWriter.setAppendAllowed(true);
```

See docs [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemWriter.html#setAppendAllowed%28boolean%29).

Comment: I put `super.setAppendAllowed(true);` first line of my class that extends `FlatItemWriter<>` in the method `write`. Still, only the stuff written in the last step is in the output file.

Comment: Well ... instead I put it in the job xml file. Works like extected. Marked as resolved, thanks !!